# How to order QGIS raster layer style?

Tags: qgis, raster, style

I have single band raster files that I am trying to style using Singleband pseudocolour under the Layer Properties, Style settings, and a colour map textfile that I upload for styling. When I upload the colour map, it looks alright, in the order I want it to be
[image: Style in the right order, from min to max]

However, after I apply the style, and look back in the Properties, the order seems to be messed up

[image: Style in a messed up order]

I know there are multiple 0 values for which I have determined a different colour, but I would like the lightest colour for all the 0 values. Is there any way to ensure the colour is displayed in the specified order from top to bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that whenever you access the **Style** properties and click either *OK* or *Apply*, the colour items with the same values have their orders swicted (in my case, they get reversed).

I think the workaround at the moment is to:

- **Load the colour map and do not access the Style tab a second time**

Or if you do need to access it then:

- **Reload the colour map before accepting any changes**

Not sure if this is indeed a bug or if the Style properties just re-classifies the values but you can report it [here](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis).

Comment: Does not seem to be an issue many others are facing though. By 'load the colour map and not access the Style tab', did you mean not access the Style tab a second time, after loading it? As long as the colours are rendered correctly the first time I guess that would be fine. Thanks!

Comment: @JocelyneSze - Apologies, yes I meant not accessing it the second time. Will edit the post to reflect that. And most welcome =)